# With CSS how can I smoothly change a div's width from 80% of container to 100% of container as container shrinks down from 1000px to 600px?

Tags: css

I'd like to have a div be 80% of its container's width, when that width is 1000px or greater.

I'd like it to be 100% of my its container's width, when that width is 600px or smaller.

In the middle I'd like it to be, well, in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayjtr1q4/9/

```css
div {
  background: #def;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  div {
    width: 80%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  div {
    /* what goes in here? */
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  As you resize the screen this snaps from 80% to 100%. I'd like to achieve a smooth transition between the two instead, so that if you set it to 800px wide you'll end up with a div that's 90% of that, i.e. 720px.
</div>
```

**ContainerSize -> divSizeAs% (divSizeInPixels)**

- 400px -> 100% (400px)
- 500px -> 100% (500px)
- 600px -> 100% (600px)
- 700px -> 95% (665px)
- 800px -> 90% (720px)
- 900px -> 85% (765px)
- 1000px -> 80% (800px)
- 1100px -> 80% (880px)
- 1200px -> 80% (960px)

Etc.

I know I could set a dozen media queries with breakpoints, but I'd rather it was a smooth transition, if possible.

I feel I could do something clever with `calc`, but am having a bit of a blank and can't quite get my head around what! But then I guess you'd need some max/min functionality, which I don't believe CSS has?

My middle-ground I've come up with so far is 3 media queries. One for >= 1000px (`width:800%`), one for <= 600px (`width:100%`) and one for in the middle... But even then I can't work out what my rules for the middle-ground should be?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was too self-explanatory.  Fiddle & code added.

Comment: You would need JS for this, the `calc` function in CSS is not capable of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with Calc. You are only concerned with the amount of space over 600px (100% - 600px), and the increment is the total space to smooth (400px). I'm not really a mathematician, maybe someone else (smarter) can give you a better equation.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px) and (max-width:600px){
  #container{
    width: calc(100% - ((100% - 600px) * 0.466));
  }
}
```

**Full code snippet:**

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 20px;
}  

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
  #container{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  #container{
    background: green;
    width: calc(100% - ((100% - 600px) * 0.466));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat more elegant way to achieve what you're looking for, using only one breakpoint. Also, I recommend [using `em` instead of `px` for your breakpoints](https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/).

```css
div {
  background: #def;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6.25em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* 37.5em = 600px */
@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  div {
    background: #fed;
    /* Replace .5 with whatever value
       looks best in your layout */
    width: calc(37.5em + ((100% - 37.5em) * .5));
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  As you resize the screen this snaps from 80% to 100%. I'd like to achieve a smooth transition between the two instead, so that if you set it to 800px wide you'll end up with a div that's 90% of that, i.e. 720px.
</div>
```

Comment: Why em rather than px?

Comment: Check out the link I posted. Basically, `em` units are more reliable when the user zooms in/out of the page.